# Pipedream : Make a Condition before Executing an Action

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, upsert, coda, pipedream

I was tasked to automate updating rows in Coda. I am currently testing out upsert rows. I want to configure it to only run if the value of {{steps.trigger.event.body.references[2].name}} is ‘add_to_Coda’. How am I going to do that in pipe dream ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `Filter` action -> `Continue execution if a condition Is met` right before the action to update rows.

- Initial value: {{steps.trigger.event.body.references[2].name}}
- Condition: [Text] Matches exactly
- Second value: add_to_Coda

Answer (score 0):

Using the `filter` step as already pointed out will work for your case.
It is however pretty inflexible tool - your check must be against a string and won't work if it has `null` value or if it's a boolean.

I personally use a nodeJS step e.g.:

```
export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    if(steps.trigger.event.properties["Automation Status"].select 
      && steps.trigger.event.properties["Automation Status"].select.name
      && steps.trigger.event.properties["Automation Status"].select.name.includes("To Do")) {
        return;
      }
    return $.flow.exit()
  },
})
```

Basically you can do all you checks and return `$.flow.exit()` if you don't want to continue with the pipe, and simply `return` if you do.